# Why did Ozai confront Ursa (The Search Part 2)

Tags: comics, avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

In the *[Search Part 2](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Search_Part_2)*, it was revealed that Ursa faked the letter she wrote regarding Zuko's true parentage to provoke Ozai and to see if he was intercepting her letters home. Ozai, angry, confronted her. Ursa told him that Zuko was his son and it was a lie, to which he responded by telling her that he **"knew it was a lie"**, as he had her followed for months prior to their wedding.

If that's the case, **why did he even confront her on the matter instead of just ignoring it**?

Answer (score 3):

Because the letter proves that Ursa is very well aware that Ozai is intercepting her messages. By writing a blatant lie, she's technically saying "dude Ozai I know you're reading this". In a way, this letter is actually meant to Ozai and it is Ursa the one that is confronting him.

So basically he can't just pretend to be oblivious of her letters since she literally let him know that she's aware.

Comment: Good call! I can't wait for the next volume to come out of the Avatar comics =]